# if check for null in integer type array- C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, null

I have following lines of code, According to Command List Item, it should goes into if block, but it is not going there. In debug mode `int[] ckeys` shows just `{int[0]}` not any value, can you tell me what is the problem?

```
List<string> Command=new List<string>();
string ASCLICAL = "Callers:";
string ASCLIMEM= "Members:";
string ASCLINOCAL="NoCallers";

int[] ckeys = Command.Select((s, idx) => new { Str = s, Idx = idx })
                    .Where(p => p.Str == ASCLICAL)
                    .Select(p => p.Idx)
                    .ToArray();

if(ckeys == null) {
                    ckeys = Command.Select((s, idx) => new { Str = s, Idx = idx })
                            .Where(p => p.Str == ASCLINOCAL)
                            .Select(p => p.Idx)
                            .ToArray();
            }
```

Command List Contains:

```
[0] = "300 has 0 calls (max unlimited) in 'ringall' strategy (173s holdtime), W:0, C:1, A:0, SL:0.0% within 0s"
[1] = "Members:"
[2] = "Local/409@from-internal/n (In use) has taken 1 calls (last was 64167 secs ago)"
[3] = "No Callers"
[4] = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never be null.  If the array does not contain elements, then it will always be an array with 0 elements.

You can use `Array.Length` or `Array.Count` and check if the size > 0

```
   if (ckeys.Length == 0) {

   }
```

Comment: okay, but how can we check for 0 element in an array in if clause?

Comment: `!ckeys.Any()` would be fine

Comment: @aemyme - check my update I have shown you how to combine this in your conditional statement

Answer (score 1):

`ckeys` is not null, it's empty. You should change `ckeys == null` to `ckeys.Length == 0`